# Error when using jQuery "on" with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a rails application that deals with dynamically generated forms (I have been following a railscasts tutorial, and I've transcribed the coffeescript to regular JS)

I have a simple HTML structure that looks similar to this (I've shortened it for the sake of brevity.)

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input>
        <a class="remove_fields"> Remove </a>
    </fieldset>

</form>

<a class="add_fields"> Add fields </a>
```

The first `a` class uses the following javascript to find and hide the nearest `fieldset` item.  I've used `.on` as opposed to `.click` since may fieldsets will be dynamically generated.

```
$('form').on('click', '.remove_fields', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide();
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log('works!');
});
```

However, when I run this code, I get a *warning* of `Empty string passed to getElementById()`, and the code does not run or log the string `works!` to the console.  It is odd that a *warning* is apparently breaking the code and throwing me no errors.

If I use `$('form').click(function()...` everything works correctly, except for the fact that dynamically generated `<fieldset>`s will not be bound to the event.

I'm wondering if perhaps the reference to `$(this)` is referring to the `$(form)` object as opposed to the `$('.remove_fields')` object?

I am using Firefox, if that is of use.

Thanks.

edit: here's what the actual form builder is looking like, if that's useful.

```
  <fieldset>
  <div class="field third">
    <%= f.label :weekday %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:weekday_id, Weekday.all, :id, :day, class: 'input') %>
  </div>
  <div class="field third">
    <%= f.label :start_time %>
    <%= f.select(:start_time, Classtime::TIMES) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field third">
    <%= f.label :end_time %>
    <%= f.select(:end_time, Classtime::TIMES) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to 'remove','#', class: 'remove_fields' %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Wait a second, that error doesn't seem to be related to this code at all, there are no ID's anywhere? Also, you say it works, but the fieldset is not  a parent of the clicked anchor, there's no way that works ?

Comment: Updated with the code I have without that mistake, sorry.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue on codepen.io?

Comment: try : `$(document).on('click', '.remove_fields', function(event) {`

Comment: I'm curious, why would `document` work and not `form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out.

It had something to do with the `.remove_fields` element being an `anchor`.  I simply changed it to a `div` and it worked with a small modification - I used `$(form)` instead of `$(fieldset)`

I'm not sure why it cannot be a link - if anyone has a better explanation, I'll gladly change my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input>
    </fieldset>
    <a id="remove_fields"> Remove </a>
</form>
<a class="add_fields">Add fields </a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#remove_fields').on('click',function(event) {
  $(this).prev('fieldset').hide();
  event.preventDefault(); 
  console.log('works!');
});
```

Note the inclusion of the `id` attribute and the use of the `<a>` tag `id` attribute as selector. Also the use of `.prev()` instead of `.closest()`.

Comment: did you read "since may fieldsets will be dynamically generated", so this code can never work on future elments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Mark is right, however. This code will not work with further generated instances of `remove_fields`.